# React fetch post custom hook is not saving data in state

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hooks

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a custom hook to send a request to an API to create a new user. The post method is working as it sends the data and creates a new user in the database. But when I try to save that data in a state to use in another component it doesn't do it, the state is always empty.

Here is the code for the custom hook for the fetch POST:

```
export default function useFetchPost(path, body) {
    const [respuestaAPI, setRespuestaAPI] = useState({});
    const [status, setStatus] = useState();
    const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        const payload = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        };
        setPending(true);
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080" + path, payload);
        const datos = await response.json();
        setRespuestaAPI(datos);
        console.log(datos);
        console.log(respuestaAPI);
        setPending(false);
        setStatus(response.ok)
    }, [path, JSON.stringify(body)])

    return { respuestaAPI, fetchData, pending, status }
}
```

The console log of "datos" returns the data just fine, but the one of "respuestaAPI" is empty.

Here is the code where I implement it in a form:

```
const usuario = {
    nombre: values.username,
    apellido: values.lastname,
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password,
    ciudad: usuarioEncontrado.ciudad,
    token: ""
  }

const { respuestaAPI, fetchData, pending } = useFetchPost("/usuario", usuario);

const handleClick = () => {
    fetchData()
    console.log("respuestaAPI")
    console.log(respuestaAPI)
    if ("status") {
      //guardar en localStorage el token, nombre, apellido y mail
      window.localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(usuario));
      //loguear al usuario con el contextoLogin
      handleLogin(true);
    }
    else {
      //retornar "Lamentablemente no ha podido registrarse. Por favor intente más tarde"
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        usuarioNoCreado: "Lamentablemente no ha podido registrarse. Por favor intente más tarde”"
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `setState` is an async function. Just make output your data in browser like `{respuestaAPI}` and I'm pretty sure you will see your data changes.

Comment: you're right! I couldn't show it in output browser because it's an object but I logged it from an useEffect and it has the data. How can I use that data to decide if I should save it in local storage or show an error?

Comment: There are two ways. First - `useEffect(() => {set error here if respuestaAPI failed}, [respuestaAPI])`, and second - `try-catch` block inside your async function. I'd prefer  the second one.